# Which level of compression should I use a .iso file

Tags: windows-8, iso-image, compression

I have an .iso file on my hard drive (on a windows 8 pc) and it is rather large (around 16 GB). I was trying to compress it (using 7-zip) so it could fit on a DVD-R. But when it finished compressing it remained too large to be written. (15 GB). I was using the default settings. ( normal compression level. deflate method ) and I was wondering if changing the settings in some way would produce a smaller file size.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood what you want to do. You want to compress an ISO image and burn the archive containing an ISO on a DVD?

Comment: You can effectively compress files **within** an ISO image, but not the complete ISO image itself. You'd need to create a new ISO image with files already compressed. Some files are already compressed, e.g. JPEG asn MP4, so further compression may not achieve anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Law of diminishing returns.

[image: Law of Diminishing Returns]

If "normal" compression got your file from 16GB to 15GB, then "max" compression won't help much more. If you're lucky you might get 13~14GB.